# How to reduce nesting when mapping through nested object properties?

Tags: javascript, nested, lodash, map-function

In my function I have the following variable:

```
const updatedData = data.map(elements => {
  return {...elements, information: {programs: elements.programs.map(program => {
    return {...program, pids: program.pids.map(pid => {
      return {
        ...pid,
        type: someFunction(pid.type),
      };
    })};
  })}};
});
```

As you see, I need to map through the very much nested property. I use the `map` function three times! Is there a way I can make this look more readable? This number of nestings make it difficult to grasp what's going on. Maybe there's a `lodash` function I can use for that?